# Rails App: MySQL socket error when using AWS Redis Elasticache, ActiveJob and Sidekiq

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sockets, amazon-web-services, redis

I have setup Sidekiq with Redis on a Rails 4.2 app.

Sidekiq works perfectly on my development environment. I can see the worker queue and it all processing correctly.

However when I publish to production I get on all ActiveJob requests.

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Here is my production setup:

**AWS**

- Redis - ElastiCache : *.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
- EC2 - ElasticBeanstalk
- Mysqsl - RDS
- Ruby - Ruby 2.1 (Passenger Standalone)

**Sideqik Gem installed - Config**

```
redis_url = Rails.env.production? ? 'redis://*.cache.amazonaws.com:6379' : 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: redis_url }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: redis_url }
end
```

**MYSQL2 Gemfile**

gem 'mysql2'

**Sideqik Stats on Prod**

Everything is processed except ActiveJob requests.

```
--- !ruby/object:Sidekiq::Stats
stats:
  :processed: 18
  :failed: 15
  :scheduled_size: 0
  :retry_size: 0
  :dead_size: 0
  :processes_size: 1
  :default_queue_latency: 0
  :workers_size: 0
  :enqueued: 3
```

**Database YML**

```
  default: &default
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8mb4
    pool: 5
    username: root
    password:
    socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

  production:
    <<: *default
    database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
    username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
    password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
    host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
    port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
    pool: 25
```

**ElasticBeanstalk Sidekiq Config**

```
## .ebextensions/sidekiq.config
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/50_restart_sidekiq":
    mode: "000777"
    content: |
      cd /var/app/current

      if [ -f /var/app/support/pids/sidekiq.pid ]
      then
        kill -TERM `cat /var/app/support/pids/sidekiq.pid`
        rm -rf /var/app/support/pids/sidekiq.pid
      fi

      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars.d/sysenv

      sleep 10

      bundle exec sidekiq \
        -e production \
        -P /var/app/support/pids/sidekiq.pid \
        -L /var/app/support/logs/sidekiq.log \
        -q default mailers \
        -d

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03_mute_sidekiq":
    mode: "000777"
    content: |
      if [ -f /var/app/support/pids/sidekiq.pid ]
      then
        kill -USR1 `cat /var/app/support/pids/sidekiq.pid`
      fi
```

**The ActiveJob**

```
class ActivitiesJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(activity)

    Activity.create( 
      team_id: activity[:team_id], 
      account_id: activity[:account_id],
      entity: activity[:entity] || nil,
      entity_id: activity[:entity_id] || nil,
      description: activity[:description],
      activity_type: activity[:activity_type].nil? ? nil : activity[:activity_type] 
    );
  end
end
```

Would like to get any opinion on why I would be getting a Socket error.

Comment: What's in default settings in database.yml?

Comment: @Jeiwan - I have updated the question with the default spec for database.yml. however, removing the inheritance of default from the production area still produces the problem.

Comment: Also note, that my connection to the MySQL DB is working anywhere else. Normal application code through ActiveRecord is working fine. Only ActiveJob requests are producing this error.

Comment: Do you get the error on all jobs? Or only on those that do some operations with DB?
Try to create a new job that prints this `Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]` into logs and see what it will print. It seems like it uses some other DB settings when dealing with SQL requests in jobs.
And check the ENV variables.

Comment: Only the ones that need to connect to the DB. I have another one that touches and API and no error. I'll have a go at getting some logs.

Comment: Sorry. Having trouble getting the logs. Will do soon but it definitely seems like the problem. I researched it and others are having trouble pointing their Sidekiq implementation to their DB YML file.

Comment: It also can be this https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/134
You need to print ENV variables in a job as well, to see if they're correct.

Comment: Yeah good call. Had a look at these. Im not using any of these Environmental variable loaders. I was just hoping Sidekiq would pick these up automatically from normal rails config files.